# Screen brightness control not working on Lenovo T530

Tags: nvidia, brightness, lenovo

My brightness control doesn't work with a fresh install of 12.10 (brand new laptop). It is set to the brightest setting when I boot up and when I try to change it, I see the notification bar come up but the brightness doesn't actually change. I've tried all the solutions I could find around the Internet but none of them work. Things I have tried include:

> Editing /sys/class/backlight/acpi_video0/brightness
>
> In /usr/share/X11/xorg.conf.d/10-brightness-control.conf: Option
>   "RegistryDwords" "EnableBrightnessControl=1"
>
> In /etc/default/grub: GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash
>   acpi_osi=Linux acpi_backlight=vendor"

There is no xorg.conf file in 12.10 that I have found, so the solutions that suggest editing that file don't do me a whole lot of good.

I am currently using the Nouveau driver, but switching to the Nvidia proprietary drivers made no difference.

Any other ideas? When is this bug going to be fixed? With all the reports I've come across I would think it would get a lot of attention. Thanks.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I had a similar problem on my thinkpad W530.  I finally found a solution here:

http://blog.pearce.org.nz/2012/08/enabling-external-monitor-on-lenovo.html

> These days X automatically configures itself, so you can't just edit the xorg.conf file, you instead need to add a section to a file in /usr/share/X11/xorg.conf.d/ and X will include that section in the configuration that it automatically generates.
>
> So to get the screen brightness keys working with your Nvidia graphics card, create a file in the xorg.conf.d directory, e.g:

```
sudo gedit /usr/share/X11/xorg.conf.d/10-nvidia-brightness.conf
```

> Paste the following into the file:

```
Section "Device"
    Identifier     "Device0"
    Driver         "nvidia"
    VendorName     "NVIDIA Corporation"
    BoardName      "Quadro K1000M"
    Option         "RegistryDwords" "EnableBrightnessControl=1"
EndSection
```

Comment: +100... i've been switching to a virtual console to use my brightness controls for an embarrassing amount of time

Comment: [Here](https://mzanfardino.wordpress.com/2015/02/10/linux-enabling-brightness-control-for-thinkpad-w520/) you can find really nice summary of the same problem.

Comment: I have an AMD powered graphics card on my ThinkPad E460. What do I need to change in this file?

Answer (score 1):

Did Ubuntu backported patches from Kernel 3.7 to 3.6? That could be the cause, see here:
https://bugzilla.kernel.org/show_bug.cgi?id=51231

Try to use the brightness slider vom "System Settings" > "Brightness & Lock" in GNOME.

Comment: Tried the slider, no change.

Answer (score 0):

Have you updated grub (`sudo update grub`) after you edit `/etc/default/grub` and rebooted?

If above not working Also try with `acpi_backlight=vendor` only.

If it is a thinkpad `thinkpad-acpi.brightness_enable=1` parameter is also required.

You can check to see if your system uses the thinkpad-acpi driver by using the following command:

`lsmod | grep thinkpad_acpi`

Check [this page](https://wiki.kubuntu.org/Kernel/Debugging/Backlight) (See first paragraph & Diagnostic Techniques)

---

**Update :**

Another thing I just show, have you edited `/etc/X11/xorg.conf` file? in your question you are pointing to some other location which I never heard of. Execute `nvidia-xconfig`
to generate config file, if `/etc/X11/xorg.conf` doesn't exist.

Secondly, try one solution at one time. if that doesn't work revert back and reboot then try other solution.

*Another workaround could be*

Try following for paths shown by `ls /sys/class/backlight/*/brightness` and replace accordingly.

example paths will be like

```
/sys/class/backlight/acpi_video0/brightness
```

1. For the above path Get the maximum brightness:

`cat  /sys/class/backlight/acpi_video0/max_brightness`

Try a lower value to set the brightness, say output is 16 so I will try with half of it

`echo 8 | sudo tee  /sys/class/backlight/acpi_video0/brightness`

**If this works**,  make this happen in each login automatically by doing the following

`sudo gedit /etc/rc.local`

Enter this line just before `exit 0`. It should look like

```
echo YOUR_VALUE_HERE > /sys/class/backlight/acpi_video0/brightness
exit 0
```

Also you can try with [xdotool](http://apt.ubuntu.com/p/xdotool) [image: Install xdotool]

Comment: Thanks for pointing me to the diagnostics page, but none of the ideas there worked either. I filed a bug on Launchpad as per the instructions there. Any other suggestions?

Comment: See the updated answer

Comment: I tried all those ideas too. None of them changed the brightness. I noticed this output from dmesg. Does any of it point you to another theory? Thanks so much for looking at this with me.

Comment: [    2.544835] thinkpad_acpi: This ThinkPad has standard ACPI backlight brightness control, supported by the ACPI video driver
[    2.544838] thinkpad_acpi: Disabling thinkpad-acpi brightness events by default...
[    2.549966] thinkpad_acpi: Standard ACPI backlight interface available, not loading native one
\[    2.589309] ACPI Warning: 0x0000000000000460-0x000000000000047f SystemIO conflicts with Region \_SB_.PCI0.LPC_.PMIO 1 (20120320/utaddress-251)
[    2.589323] ACPI: If an ACPI driver is available for this device, you should use it instead of the native driver

Answer (score -1):

This is kind of a workaroun, but you can try setting the brightness via command line using:

```
xbacklight -set 100
```

If that works, trying binding a global keyboard shortcut to

```
xbacklight -inc 5
```

and

```
xbacklight -dec 5
```